# how post entire page in GWT form panel

Tags: java, forms, gwt

While using GWT FormPanel, after submitting the form, it posts form but does not redirect to the action url.
Can any body help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
formPanelObject.getElement().<FormElement>cast().setTarget("");
```

by this line you changing the target parameter of the form and now the main page redirected to the action url after calling formPanelObject.submit();.

Comment: is there any way to display some message on new page which is blank currently?